# .NET System.Windows.Forms DateTimePicker CustomFormat incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, format, datetimepicker

Here's the code:

```
   DateTime dt = new DateTime( 2016, 8, 3);
   dtpStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dtpStart.CustomFormat = "Mdyyyy"; //format;
   dtpStart.Value = dt;
   string s = String.Format( "{0:Mdyyyy}", dt );
   System.Console.Write( s );
```

In the DateTimePicker (dtpStart) I see **" 8 32016"**, which has the month and day each *left-padded with a space*, while the console output shows the expected value **"832016"**.

The problem is that we're seeing this unexpected padding of the month and day, regardless of the format we supply, e.g.:

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`

Comment: Side note: There probably are worse choices of date time format than "Mdyyyy"... "1112016".

Comment: as per your custom format **" 8 32016"**, use this `string s = String.Format("{0: M dyyyy}", dt);`. make sure you add the space as per your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DateTimePicker` control is trying to be helpful and let you enter a date manually with the keyboard instead of the dropdown. If the numbers were displayed without spaces the date would be ambiguous. For example, what date does this refer to:

```
1232016
```

Is it `December 3, 2016` or `January 23, 2016`? So the spaces are required. Your best bet is to give the day and month values a leading zero:

```
dtpStart.CustomFormat = "MMddyyyy";
```

Comment: Thanks DavidG.  Perhaps my example was poorly chosen, but it was to illustrate the point that spaces seem *always* to be inserted before the month and day.  In our production code we would like to use the client's locale-specific "short-date" format as provided by the CultureInfo, (e.g. M/d/yyyy for 1033) but there we were getting extra spaces too.  I'll try your suggestion in the morning to see if I can force leading zeros, as that might be more acceptable.  If that works I may have to create a custom set of locale-specific formats. Nevertheless, thanks for the suggestion